# create table as select Join statement not working in hive

Tags: sql, hive

With the command:

```
hive -e "create table C as 
         (select * from A a 
         left join T t on a.seller_id = t.seller_id 
         where day=31 and month=1 and year=31)"
```

I get the following error:

> cannot recognize input near 'left' 'join' 'T' in join type specifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries

> Hive supports subqueries only in the FROM clause.

Maybe:

```
create table C as select * from (select * from A a left join T t on a.seller_id = t.seller_id where day =31 and month = 1 and year = 31 )x"
```

Answer (score 1):

it just shuold be left **outer** join